# How to clone a Xamarin Project and have it build right away

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project on my laptop, and am switching laptops. It is a Xamarin Android project with C#. It is source controlled onto visual studio online / devops using the Git option. When I clone my project onto my new laptop. My project is not building. Some projects aren't loading and some of my references have errors next to them.

I think to get it working requires some necessary steps. Please tell me if any of this should not be necessary.

(1) Open Visual Studio Installer and Modify in order to add Mobile Development and .Net so that Xamarin is installed.
(2) Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager > Checkmark necessary SDKs (aka android Lollipop, etc). (If these are failing, then right click on visual studio icon to "Run as Administrator" when initially opening.

This third step is whats bothering me: 
(3) Clean Solution and Rebuild. And magically every dependency and every necessary anything is automatically installed/etc.. but not true.

Instead... 
Some references in your projects will have a yellow triangle icon. Go to Tools > Nuget Package Manager and when you select any of the Installed projects, there will NOT be a checkmark next to ANY projects.. weird.. but when you go to Update, and click on any needing an update, the checkmark will be there. If you select all and update, some of your yellow triangles will go away, but the checkmarks won't appear in Installed when clicking on a project and seeing which projects it is installed in on the right.

Is there some button or command I am supposed to run that will grab all the necessary dependencies for me? Instead of me having to dig around and still have a non working solution?

Comment: please add a diagnostic build output about this issue. (As a file attachment or gist link), that would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for all the projects to build correctly I believe the following order is necessary: (As OP, I downloaded and tried to build the project before checking to make sure I had Xamarin and the necessary SDKs, and once those were installed, it wouldn't fix the project without deleting and recloning)

(1) Do NOT clone your project from github/devops yet. Delete it if you have.

(2) Install Xamarin. Open Visual Studio Installer and Modify in order to add Mobile Development and .Net so that Xamarin is installed.

(3) Install necessary SDKs for Android OS version. Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager > Checkmark necessary SDKs (aka android Lollipop, etc). (If these are failing, then right click on visual studio icon to "Run as Administrator" when initially opening.

(4) Clone project from github/devops, and clean/build. Should work automatically.

(An aside: I feel like step 3 should also be automatic? It should know which ones I'm targeting and auto install those? Maybe it does, I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some examples of the error messages you are getting? Usually Project Load - Restore Nuget Packages - Clean & Rebuild works for me.

Comment: In my Solution Explorer, when I open a project, and then it's references section, one of my references has a yellow warning triangle next to it. Hovering it produces no error, but when I am "using Android.Support.Core.UI" in my project, it says it can't find it. I also notice when I click on the reference item in references, the properties window shows no PATH for that reference.

Comment: (1) Project Load. (2) Restore Nuget Packages. (3) Clean & Rebuild. Could you elaborate on 1 and 2? For 1, when I open my Solution all projects are loaded (unless I forgot to download Xamarin or Android SDKs). I can right click on the projects in Solution Explorer and to Project Unload, and then Project Load (or just Project Load if it happens to be unloaded). For 2, I don't see a button or right click option or anything that says "Restore Nuget Packages". How does one access that option?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see it, or maybe it was not available. But I did find "Restore Nuget Packages" as an option in the right-click dropdown on the top level solution in Solution Explorer

Answer (score 0):

NuGet will download the packages available in the package manager. However it may happen that some packages where not installed through the sources available in the package manager or that those packages are not available anymore.